# Orleans Inter-Silo Communication using streams

Tags: distributed-computing, orleans

I have two Silos Silo A and Silo B each having its own distinct grain and interface. I need to have them both communicate via streams. How possible is this? I am running locally for now and using SMS InMemory storage. within the same silo streaming works, how can this be achieved across silos

Answer (score 2):

If you have grain a on silo A that wants to communicate via stream with grain a on silo B, just produce to a stream from a and subscribe to consume from b, and it will work.

Comment: what if they are different grains. Say Silo A contains Grains of A and Silo B contains Grains of B but Grain B need to know when something special happens in Silo A

Comment: In such a case they can use direct grain messaging (regular grain to grain calls) to communicate to B when something special happens in A. The stream allows to decouple the producer from the consumer (they don't need to know about each other), but if you need them to know about each other - just use regular grain calls.